# rsync error on downloading from archive.ubuntu.com

Tags: ubuntu

Sir I am trying to setup a Rsyncmirror on my mount drive /mnt/Mirror/ubuntu_mirror .so I am trying the command
rsync -a --bwlimit=128 rsync://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu /mnt/Mirror/ubuntu_mirror but it shows error

rsync: getaddrinfo: archive.ubuntu.com 873: Name or service not known                      rsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at clientserver.c(122) [Receiver=3.0.9]

can anyone help me..
 Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

rsync -aPz --bwlimit=128 rsync://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mirror
Is working for me.

Typically this error has to do with not being able to resolve the IP address of the host.  Verify that the host archive.ubuntu.com resolves on your system.

Comment: I add my proxy ip on /etc/resolv.conf and tryed with above command but now I am facing a new problem                                   rsync: failed to connect to archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.92.177): Connection refused (111)
rsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at clientserver.c(122) [Receiver=3.0.9]
can anyone suggest me ??

Comment: Do you have a firewall blocking port 873?  Try:

"telnet 91.189.92.200 873"

You should get something like:
@RSYNCD: 30.0

Comment: thanks for replay     but It shows error as                     Trying 91.189.92.156...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

Comment: You must have some kind of firewall blocking connections, try turning off any firewalls and try to connect from a different network.  In any firewall that you do have set up, make sure to allow TCP port 873 outbound.